# Return result after reader read image convert to base 64

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64, filereader

I have a test on the functions after click the button the image will convert to base64 and return the result but it gives me blank. Why?

```
    $("#addNewProduct").click(function(){
        var uploadpImg1 = converttobase64(document.getElementById("uploadpImg1-input"));
        var uploadpImg2 = converttobase64(document.getElementById("uploadpImg2-input"));
        var uploadpImg3 = converttobase64(document.getElementById("uploadpImg3-input"));
        alert(uploadpImg1);
    });     
 function converttobase64(element) {
      var result ="";
      var file = element.files[0];

      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onloadend = function() {

        result = reader.result;       

      }

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to image load ( asynchrone process ) , using callck back function fix the problem

You'll see always an empty string even the base64 image is generated , because of the asynchrone proccess ,

What you can do is pass a `callback` function , in which you can put your after generation intruction ( your alert ) 
 , and call this last on the  `onloadend` by passing the result as param in the callback function

See below Snippet :

```js
$("#addNewProduct").click(function() {
  var uploadpImg1 = converttobase64(document.getElementById("uploadpImg1-input"), function(result) {
    alert(result);
  });

});

function converttobase64(element, callback) {
  var result = "";
  var file = element.files[0];
  
  if (typeof(file) == 'undefined') return;

  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function() {

    result = reader.result;
    callback(result);
  }

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="file" id="uploadpImg1-input" />

<button id="addNewProduct">add</button>
```

Comment: @rrr_rrr does it help !